# passing data from executed script to background in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this idea for passing data form an injected script (getDOM.js) to my background.js

**bacgkround.js**

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "getDOM.js"})
});


chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "GetURL"}, function(response) {
            alert(response.navURL);
      });
      });
});
```

**getDOM.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.greeting === "GetURL")
      sendResponse({navURL:'test'});
  });
```

as you can see i used massage function to pass data, but there is a problem. i cant get data on right time, i will pass background.js previous data

content must be dynamic (not specific "test"), every time it will alert previous data. imagine getDOM.js will pass selected text, with this code it will pas previous selected text. how can i fix this ?

my example of dynamic data :

```
function getHTMLOfSelection () {
      var range;
      if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        return range.htmlText;
      }
      else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
          range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
          var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
          return div.innerHTML;
        }
        else {
          return '';
        }
      }
      else {
        return '';
      }
}

var dom = getHTMLOfSelection();
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.greeting === "getDom")
      sendResponse({DOM:dom});
  });
```

it will pass selected dom to background.js

Comment: Can you please add an example that _shows_ the problem? I.e. dynamic data.

Comment: i just updated the question. i can't regenerate the problem anymore, i don't know how that possible but the problem is gone now !!. but problem can be back (i don't know how !) and there is another problem : context menu should be fire once to work fine after that

Comment: i think the problem is with the time that js will be injected, it should be injected on start. can u help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of problems here. Let's see.

1. It does not make sense to execute `getHTMLOfSelection()` at the point when the script is injected. You probably should put that inside the message handler: to get the selection *when asked to*.
2. A much bigger problem is the fact that every time you inject a script. This, together with 1, leads to all kinds of *fun*. Let's look in more detail!

   - The user triggers the context menu.
   - Your first `contextMenu.onClicked` handler runs. The script injection is *scheduled*. It's asynchronous, so you don't know when it will finish unless you use a callback. Which you don't.
   - Your second `contextMenu.onClicked` handler runs. It sends a message to a script which potentially haven't finished executing. If you're lucky, you get a response.
   - User triggers the context menu again on the same page.
   - Your first `contextMenu.onClicked` handler runs, again. The script is going to be injected *again*, creating a *second* listener for the message that will compete with the first. It's again asynchronous, so *maybe* by the time your message arrives `dom` is up to date. Maybe not.
   - Your second `contextMenu.onClicked` handler runs, again. This time there sure is a message listener (maybe two!) that returns *maybe* up to date data.

   And so on. You see the problem?
3. Furthermore, you *can't* pass a DOM object with `sendResponse`. The object needs to be JSON-serializable, and DOM objects contain circular references, which is a no-no. You need to extract the data you need on the content script side, and pass only that.

So, let's try to tackle those problems.

There are 2 ways of dealing with this. I'll present both, pick the one you prefer. Both will take care of problems 1 and 2.

**First way** is to ensure your message handler is only added once by including some kind of guard variable:

```
// getDOM.js

if(!getDOM_ready) { // This will be undefined the first time around
  getDOM_ready = true;
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      // If only you knew how I hate this "greeting" example copied over
      if (request.command === "GetURL") {
        var dom = getHTMLOfSelection();
        sendResponse({DOM: dom});
      }
    }
  );
}

function getHTMLOfSelection() {
  /* ... */
}
```

Then on the background side, we need to be sure we send a message only after the script finishes executing:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "getDOM.js"}, function() {
    // This only executes after the content script runs
    // Oh, and you most certainly don't need to query for tabs,
    //   you already have a tab and its id in `onClicked`
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {command: "GetURL"}, function(response) {
      alert(response.navURL);
    });
});
```

The **second way** is to drop Messaging altogether. `executeScript` actually returns the last value the content script evaluated. That makes the content script trivial and does not leave a message listener behind:

```
// getDOM.js
function getHTMLOfSelection() {
  /* ... */
}

getHTMLOfSelection(); // Yes, that's it
```

On the background side, you need to adapt the listener:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "getDOM.js"}, function(results) {
    // results is an array, because it can be executed in more than one frame
    alert(results[0]);
});
```

The code is much simpler here, AND it does not leave an active event listener behind.

As for problem 3, you need to extract the info you need (say, a link) from the selection and pass only that instead of the object.

---

Finally, this is not a complete solution. Problem is, your selection can be inside an `iframe`, and this solution only injects code into the top frame. Solution to that is left as an exercise to the reader; using `all_frames: true` in the content script options will inject into all frames, and one of them will have a non-empty selection. You just need to see which.